# Integral of $e^x \, \ln(e^{2x} - 4)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Find the integral from $\ln 4$ to $\ln 6$ of $$e^x \ln(e^{2x} - 4)$$

I factored $$\ln(e^{2x} - 4)$$ to get $$\ln((e^{x} - 2)(e^{x} + 2))$$

Then I separated this to get:

$$e^x\ln(e^{x} - 2) + e^x\ln(e^{x} + 2)$$

So then I integrated to get $$(1/2) (\ln(e^{x} - 2))^2 + (1/2)(\ln(e^{x} + 2))^2$$

Then I attempted to evaluate the integral, but I didn't know how to simplify for example $$(\ln2)^2$$ And the available options (this is multiple choice) did not contain any such squared values. Is there a way to simplify this? Or should the question be done differently?

Comment: You integrated wrongly, try and working it out again.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$I = \int_{\ln(4)}^{\ln(6)} e^x \ln(e^{2x}-4)dx$$
Now set $t=e^x$ and we get
$$I = \int_4^6 \ln(t^2-4) dt = \int_4^6 \ln(t+2) dt + \int_4^6 \ln(t-2) dt = \int_6^8 \ln(t)dt + \int_2^4 \ln(t)dt$$
I trust you can finish it from here.

Comment: What happened to the +/- 2?

Comment: @Chrysanthemum Change of variable.  Notice the change of bounds.

Comment: You should give those variables different names to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

If the answers don't look like yours, there's chance that you've done something wrong. The integral of $\ln x$ is not $\frac{1}{2} \ln^2 x$. It's evident when you take the derivative:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{2} \ln^2 x \right) = \frac{\ln x}{x} $$

For the $\ln$ function, try integration by parts. Also, use a substitution first, don't think you can do everything in your head.

Let $t = e^x$,

$$ \int_{\ln 4}^{\ln 6} e^x \ln (e^x - 2) \, dx = \int_4^6 \ln(t-2) \, dt $$

Let 
$$u = \ln (t-2)$$
$$dv = dt$$

You'll get
$$ du = \frac{dt}{t-2} $$
$$ v = t - 2 $$

So

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\int_4^6 \ln(t-2) \, dt &= \int u\,dv \\ 
&= uv - \int v\,du \\ 
&= (t-2) \ln(t-2) \bigg|_4^6 - \int_4^6 dt \\
&= (t-2) \ln(t-2) \bigg|_4^6 - t \bigg|_4^6
\end{align*} $$

Do the same for the other integrals.